# Javascript global namespace access without same-domain?

Tags: javascript

Say domain A has:

```
window.MYNAMESPACE = somefunction(){...
```

I tried the following javascript from within an iframe of domain B:

```
<script>parent.MYNAMESPACE();</script>
```

However, the same-domain policy appears to prevent this. This is understandable, but is it possible to reach a function in this manner from within a non-same-origin domain to the parent?